# Click does not always work in Selenium

Tags: selenium, phpunit, non-deterministic

I use Selenium with PHPUnit, and sometimes test fail with an error condition which seems to be caused by the browser ignoring `clickAndWait` calls. The test execution passes the `clickAndWait` command without much delay (even if I set a large timeout), and the next assertion or element access fails; if I make a screenshot, it shows the previous page as if the click command did not happen at all. This happens both with links and with submit buttons (both normal, no `javascript:` or similar trickery), non-deterministically. It seems to happen more often on certain controls than others (many are not affected at all), and the frequency of tests failing seems more or less contant in the short term, but changes wildly in the long term (sometimes it is 1 in 100, sometimes 1 in 2). I am guessing it is influenced by some sort of server load, but could not see any obvious correlation.

Answer (score 2):

I work more with Selenium 2 but I have noticed this as well. In my case I suspect other system clicks were interfering with Selenium (purely speculation) since I ran the tests on my machine.

The way I solved it was to instead send a key press of the **Return** key. For most cases this is equivalent to a click and in my experience has created more stable tests.

A quick caveat is that this technique stopped working for me after version 2.3.0. I submitted a [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2454) about it if you want to take a look.